# Cannot replace Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lubuntu, 18.04

I have installed Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit in a pretty old PC, but then discovered the PC's processor is a 64-bit (an Intel Atom N2600, with 2GB of RAM), and decided to change the system. I had a bit of a problem with Lubuntu 18.04, so I think it may be best to install Lubuntu 16.04.

But, when I try to install it, it's impossible to boot from USB. It just shows me a black screen and is stuck on it forever. The Boot priority is okay (first option is to boot from USB) and the live stick (made with LinuxLive Creator) works perfectly in another PC.

What can I do to intall Lubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Did you sumcheck the iso?

Comment: You may want to stick with 18.04 because Lubuntu 16.04 only has about 9 months of support remaining.  Unlike Ubuntu LTS releases, which are supported for 5 years, Lubuntu is only supported for 3.

Comment: Well, I had problems with my Lubuntu 18.04, so I thought it would be better to install 16.04... Anyways, the problem persists: I cannot boot from USB to reinstall it

Comment: @Panther is it necessary? I installed that Lubuntu (I think you're talking of the 16.04) in another computer and didn't have any problem at all

Comment: @Panther In fact, today I tried to install another linux (Ubuntu 16.04, so it's a different iso) and had the same exact problem, so I don't think it is the iso

Comment: Well the first step is always to do the check sum first